# Are PostgreSQL prepared statements cached by the statement name?

Tags: database, postgresql, caching, prepared-statement

From my understanding, Postgres will cache prepared statements automatically. If I do the following in pseudo code:

```
 connect()
 prepare("statement1", SQL1, params1)
 exec_prepared("statement1")
 close()
```

Then later I do the following again

```
 connect()
 prepare("statement1", SQL2, params2)
 exec_prepared("statement1")
 close()
```

How will Postgres handle these two prepared statements from a caching point of view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [prepare documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html):

> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database
>   session. When the session ends, the prepared statement is forgotten,
>   so it must be recreated before being used again.

So the statement and it's plan does not survive closing the connection and it is not cached.